# C# Comparison operators not supported for type Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, comparison

I get a dictionary and i want to get the matching database entries for the key field in the dictionary.
So the code below gets all database fields that equals the data in the dictionary.keys. So far so good. Now when i loop it and i try to get the field from the fields that matches the key x it fails with an exception:

{"Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.String]'"}

```
var fields = _dc.fieldInfos.Where(x => x.name.Equals(param.MethodData.Keys));
foreach (var entry in param.MethodData)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> entry1 = entry;
    var field = fields.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name.Equals(entry1.Key));
    if (field == null)
    ....
}
```

The line that fails is this:

```
var field = fields.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name.Equals(entry1.Key));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be mindful that the `_dc.fieldInfos.Where(x => x.name.Equals(param.MethodData.Keys))` (line 1) **doesn't actually get executed** until you try to iterate over `fields` (line 5).

At that point, `x.name.Equals(param.MethodData.Keys)` fails because a `string` (x.name) cannot be compared to `KeyCollection<string>` (param.MethodData.Keys).

Essentially, you are getting the exception on unexpected line because of the deferred execution.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the LINQ to SQL provider cannot translate the C# expression passed to the [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx) method into an SQL statement.

You can easily solve this problem by having LINQ to SQL execute the `fields` query *before* filtering it further with the [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx) method. This way **the second operation will happen on the collection of objects in memory** instead of the database:

```
var field = fields.ToList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.name.Equals(entry1.Key));
```

**Related resources:**

- [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not this line that's failing:

```
var fields = _dc.fieldInfos.Where(x => x.name.Equals(param.MethodData.Keys));
```

as `name` isn't going to match a collection of strings.

which if so, I'd rewrite as:

```
var fields = _dc.fieldInfos.Where(x => param.MethodData.Keys.Contains(x.name));
```

`entry1.key` is a string, so I can't see why the line that you highlighted would fail with that message.

Comment: The error is introduced in the first line, but, thanks to deferred execution, the exception is thrown on first iteration - in the highlighted line. Type mentioned in exception confirms that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = _dc.fieldInfos.Where(x => x.name.Equals(param.MethodData.Keys));
```

This retrieves (actually filters with deferred execution) `fieldInfos` by matching their name to a collection of keys. I don't know what `fieldInfo.Name` and `param.MethodData.Keys` mean, but i assume it's not what you want.

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
var pairs = param.MethodData.Join(_dc.fieldInfos, 
    kvp => kvp.Key, 
    fi => fi.name, 
    (kvp, fi) => new { Key = kvp.Key, FieldInfo = fi });

foreach (var pair in pairs)
    param.MethodData[pair.Key] = pair.FieldInfo;
```

Im not exactly sure it's gonna work in Linq to SQL though.